# How to Unhide a number Cells in one sheet based on a number in another sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

Hi there i want to hide cells in Sheet 2 based on a number entered in a cell in Sheet 1

What I have tried:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'This is were im stuck? 
    If Target.Address = "Sheet1!$D$387" Then
        Rows("28:46").Hidden = True
        Rows("28:" & 28 + Val(Target.Value)).Hidden = False
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End If

End Sub
```

What is the macros to access the value of D387 in Sheet 1?

Comment: you need to put this `Worksheet_Change` sub to Sheet1 's module
Then change `Rows("28:46")` into `Sheet2.Rows("28:46")`, similiar to the line below.  And compare like : `If Target = Range("D387:D387") then`

Comment: Oh so this code will go into sheet 1's Module and not sheet 2?

Comment: `Worksheet_Change` should be put into the sheet THAT triggers the change. In your case, you are using Sheet1's D387 cell to trigger the change in Sheet2

Comment: I understand now, thanks for your help. I have posted an answer with the code that works 100%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my own solution with help from Larry(first comment on the question)

This code will go into Sheet1's Module (as suggested by Larry):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Address = "$D$387" Then
        Sheet2.Rows("27:46").Hidden = True
        Sheet2.Rows("27:" & 27 + Val(Target.Value)).Hidden = False
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End If

End Sub
```

I had originally placed it into Sheet2's Module